# Merging multiple shapefiles and finding which shapefile gives the minimum value for each attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, merge

I have several different shapefiles that I want to combine into one based on the minimum value of each attribute. I found [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307583/getting-maximum-values-of-attribute-of-multiple-shapefiles-merged-into-new-shape?newreg=ee2c4300c47b40eea96e197020a0ad46). However, I also want to know which shapefile each minimum value came from.

For example, I have 5 shapefiles with values in each one of 10 attributes. For each attribute, I found the minimum value from one of the 5 shapefiles using the method in the solution above. But I also want to know which of the 5 shapefiles the minimum value came from for each attribute. Is this possible?

Comment: Add a column to each with the shapefile name, merge, then find minimum

Comment: Thank you @BERA for your response. My MERGE shapefile already has a column of the original shapefile names. However, when I try to "Add/Edit Virtual Layer" using the method in the link above, the output layer loses the shapefile names column. Is there any way I can keep this column in the output virtual layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314843/copy-only-minimum-value-which-is-minimum-within-group-in-qgis).

I use "select" to choose which columns (in this case, "layer") I want to keep:

```
select layer, min(id), "geometry" from Merged group by attribute
```

Here, "layer" is a column in my Attribute Table with information about which shapefile each "id" came from.